# String used in session not updated automatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I used to store an object in session

```
Student stud = Student();
stud.Name = "Raja";
Session["stud"] = stud; //Assign object to session

stud = (Student)Session["stud"]; // Retrieve from session
stud.Name = "Sam"; // Now the session also updated automatically.

Response.Write(Session["stud"].ToString()); // "Sam"
```

For string

```
string Name = "Raja";
Session["name"] = Name; //Assign object to session

Name = (string)Session["name"]; // Retrieve from session
Name = "Sam"; // But here session not updated automatically

Response.Write(Session["name"].ToString()); // "Raja"
```

I have similar problem in my project. While converting the Session State to OutProc, all the objects are serialized. Actually I wanted to make the code working without pushing the updated value again to the session. Is it possible?

I am not good in English. I hope it make sense.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Immutability

Answer (score 0):

`string` by definition is immutable. When you do:

```
Name = "Sam";
```

You're actually allocating a new `string` instance. Hence, your previous `string` stored inside `Session` and the new one no longer point to the same reference, hence why you dont see it updating to the new value.

If you want to update the string stored inside `Session`, you'll have to do so directly:

```
Session["name"] = "Sam";
```

Note a string may be interned into the intern pool, but you shouldn't rely on this behavior by any measure.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two different type.

1. in first case you using reference type.

   Session["stud"] = stud;

   Here in your Session key stud hold object reference not its value. So when you retrieve in next time

   Student st = Session["stud"] you actually getting  same reference of that object and you are updating    that so it is updated in session as well.
2. Second case you are dealing with String. String is immutable type which means that once assigned it is not changed. If you change its value it will create new string object.

   ```
   string Name = "Raja";
   Session["name"] = Name; //Assign object to session
   Name = (string)Session["name"]; 
   Name = "Sam"; // Again new assignment of string.
   Response.Write(Session["name"].ToString());
   ```

To understand it properly have a look at

```
 string name = "Test";
        Session["name"] = name;
        bool status =  String.ReferenceEquals(name, Session["name"]);
        string name1 = string.Empty;
        name1 =  (string)Session["name"];            
        status = String.ReferenceEquals(name, name1);
        name1 = "test2";
        status = String.ReferenceEquals(name, name1);
```

Above last statement return false because when name1 = "test2" get executed it get assigned as new string. This is not going to happen in Student case.